# How to express a condition in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

I am a new user in GAMS and I want to write a condition but I cannot figure out the right way to express it.

I want `b(l)` to be equals `Pcost(pl)` when `Loc(l,pl)` is not zero.

Is there any way to express this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b(l) = sum(pl$Loc(l,pl), Pcost(pl));
```

The `$` is the condition sign. `pl` needs to be controlled on the right. Therefore, the `sum` is used. Assuming, that there is just one `pl` for each `l` with `Loc(l,pl)>0`, the assignment above will do, what you asked for.

Note: `$Loc(l,pl)` can be read as "if `Loc(l,pl)` is unequal to zero. If you want to be more explicit, you could also write the following (which is really the same as the first version for GAMS):

```
b(l) = sum(pl$(Loc(l,pl)<>0), Pcost(pl));
```